# How can I address the values in a vector based on start and stop indexes from other vectors?

Tags: r, vector, indexing

Let's say I have a vector full of zeros:

```
x <- rep(0, 100)
```

I want to set the values in certain ranges to 1:

```
starts <- seq(10, 90, 10)
stops <- starts + round(runif(length(starts), 1, 5))
```

I can do this with a for loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(starts)) x[starts[i]:stops[i]] <- 1
```

But I know this is frowned upon in R. How can I do this in a vectorized way, ideally without an external package?

Comment: For examples with random data, it's best to `set.seed` before taking draws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map()` to get *all* of the indices, `Reduce(union, ...)` to drop that list down to an atomic vector of the *unique* indices and then `[<-` or `replace()` to replace.

```
replace(x, Reduce(union, Map(":", starts, stops)), 1L)
```

Or

```
x[Reduce(union, Map(":", starts, stops))] <- 1L
```

Additionally, `for()` loops are not necessarily "frowned upon" in R. It depends on the situation.  Many times `for()` loops turn out to be the most efficient route.

Comment: Or just `unlist(Map(":", starts, stops))`. Didn't know about `Map`, nice solution!

Comment: Thanks.  You could do that.  But in the case of duplicated indices you would be replacing them twice and it would be less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses `apply`:

```
x[unlist(apply(cbind(starts, stops), 1, function(x) x[[1]]:x[[2]]))] <- 1
```

Comment: I think you need an `unlist()` around the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
starts <- seq(10, 90, 1)
change_index <- starts[starts %% 10 <= 5]

x[change_index] <- 1
```

Comment: My example was simplified but starts and stops are random. So a solution like this won't work.

Comment: could you provide an example that resembles the problem more?